# How to aggregate the time time between pairs of logs in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Suppose you have logs with some transaction ID and timestamp

```
12:00: transactionID1 handled by funcX
12:01: transactionID2 handled by funcX
12:03: transactionID2 handled by funcY
12:04: transactionID1 handled by funcY
```

I want to get the time between 2 logs of the same event and aggregate (e.g. sum, avg) the time difference.

For example, for transactionID1, the time diff would be (12:04 - 12:01) 3min and for transactionID2, the time diff would be (12:03 - 12:02) 1min. Then I'd like to take the average of all these time differences, so (3+1)/2 or 2min.

Is there a way to that?

Comment: Were you able to figure out a good query for this?

Comment: sorry, I did not

Comment: @kane please let me know if my suggestions would help you to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible with CloudWatch alone. I don't know where your logs come from, e.g. EC2, Lambda function. What you could do is to use the AWS SDK to [create custom metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html).

###### Approach 1

If the logs are written by the same process, you can keep a map of `transactionID` and `startTime`in memory and create a custom metric with `transactionID` as dimension and calculate the metric value with the `startTime`. In case the logs are from different processes e.g. Lambda function invocations, then you can use DynamoDB to store the `startTime`.

###### Approach 2

If the transactions are independent you could also create custom metrics per transaction and use CloudWatch [`DIFF_TIME`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) which will create a calculated metric with values for each transaction.

With CloudWatch [`AVG`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) it should then be possible to calculate the average duration.

Personally, I have used the first approach to calculate a duration across Lambda functions and other services.